# Bash - How to replace duplicated character and left only one in row

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I have file with data like below, I need to remove or replace many characters **,** in one row to make sure that I have only one **,** insted of many to create csv file.

```
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,CHF,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,198.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,169.29-,,,,,,,1.169599998,,,,,,,,,,1.165320000,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0.62
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,CNH,,,,,,,,,,,513012.53,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,65395.23-,,,,,,,7.844800000,,,,,,,,,,7.860100000,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,127.29-
```

output should be like this

```
CHF,198.00,169.29-,1.169599998,1.165320000,0.62
```

Comment: Please always try to wrap your samples in CODE TAGS `{}` button. Always try to put your efforts which you have put to solve your problem in your post too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{sub(/^,+/,"");gsub(/,+/,",")} 1' Input_file
```

Comment: it works, thanks a lot